# Google Cloud PubSub V1 using GCloud Emulator

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm fighting with Google Docs for setting up Cloud PubSub with .NET using a PubSub emulator.

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-pub-sub

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator

Coming from a Rails background, I'm tasked to implement Cloud PubSub for a .NET product, running our google cloud on .NET Core, to enable it to publish.

```
Google::Cloud::Pubsub.new(project: project_id, emulator_host: emulator_host)
```

From the documentation using .NET, I keep coming back to the following:

```
PublisherServiceApiClient publisherClient = PublisherServiceApiClient.Create();
PublisherClient publisher = PublisherClient.Create(...)
```

However, the library used from the docs `Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 -Pre`
 does not contain the definition.

`'PublisherClient' does not contain a definition for 'Create'`.

Instead, I get `CreateAsync` that takes in `TopicName`, `PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings` and `PublisherClient.Settings`.

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.PublisherClient.html

I noticed that `PublisherServiceApiClient` can take in a `Channel`, but I'm confused on how to get this going.

To conclude with an actual question, how does one currently implement Cloud PubSub with .NET for in cloud and then locally with emulator? Adding to that, am I using the wrong library or the wrong docs?

Any suggestions, pointers or piece of advice would be truly appreciated.

Comment: It’s well documented stuff, may be too much.. After searching I find this tutorial which guides you how to setup your dev environment.. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages As to why for you Create() not showing, is may be you missing a setup step..

Comment: Unfortunately that guide is for a ASP.NET app, which our application is not :/ I thought there could be some take aways from the guide, but seems like they're also using `PublisherClient.Create()`...

Comment: I think they using ASP .Net Core for HelloWorld tutorial.. There is also bigger all encompassing tutorial for Bookshelf app (probably not what you want either) https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/tutorial-app

Comment: Yeah I was initially following along using the Bookshelf app tutorial, but same issue.

Comment: In the following blog they use CreateAsync method https://www.pmichaels.net/2017/12/17/c-programmers-guide-google-cloud-pub-sub-messaging/

Comment: For `PublisherClient`, you should indeed use `CreateAsync`. We don't currently have any direct emulator support, although there's work afoot that might make that simpler. You could specify a `PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings` with a suitable `ServiceEndpoint` and `ChannelCredentials.Insecure` to talk to the emulator though. I won't add an answer to this question at the moment as it's not a clear question *to* answer - some parts appear to be about docs, some about creation, and some about the emulator. If you could clarify this to a specific question, it would be easier to add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed a solution that I am happy with.

Instead of using the `PublisherClient`, I went with using the `PublisherServiceApiClient` alone.

```
emulatorAddr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST");
if (emulatorAddr != null)
{
    channel = new Channel(emulatorAddr, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
    pub = PublisherServiceApiClient.Create(channel);
}
else
{
    pub = PublisherServiceApiClient.Create();
}
```

Which meant that publishing was slightly more involved then sending string to the `PublisherClient`, but overall not so bad.

```
PubsubMessage msg = new PubsubMessage
{
    Data = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload))
};

pub.PublishAsync(topic, new[]{ msg });
```

If the project is running in a Google Compute Engine, it will have default credentials. Otherwise, wether you're running an emulator locally or in docker you can define `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST`.

What really helped was this https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To make the `PublisherClient` connect to a local emulator, you need to pass custom `ServiceEndpoint` and `ChannelCredentials` to `CreateAsync`:

```
var serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(theEmulatorHost, theEmulatorPort);

var publisherClient = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(
    topicName,
    new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings(credentials: ChannelCredentials.Insecure, serviceEndpoint: serviceEndpoint));
```

To switch to the real PubSub, just leave away the `ClientCreationSettings`.

Comment: So you have to change code back and forth to use emulator? Sounds like a receipe for disaster to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EmulatorDetection` property on the `ClientCreationSettings` using extension method `.WithEmulatorDetection(EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOrProduction)`. Like this:

```
PublisherClient publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(
        topicName, 
        new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings()
            .WithEmulatorDetection(EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOrProduction));
```

This will work if you have the following environment variable for the local emulator endpoint: `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8085`

(If you use Visual Studio you might have to restart VS for the environment variable to be detected)

In windows I had problems using the `set PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8085` command, so I ended up adding it manually.

Details here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator

Extra tip: you can add topics directly to API using curl: `curl -X PUT http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/my-project-name/topics/my-topic`